# Stable conformers of piperazine

Tags: stereochemistry

which conformer stable of piperazine, when hydrogen of N in axial or in equatorial, or lone pair? why?

Comment: If you mean piperidine, see [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16323/steric-effects-of-a-lone-pair-and-piperidine/16333#16333); if you mean piperazine, you can apply the same thinking and conclude that the axial-equatorial preference will be even smaller (~0 kcal/mol).